# How to change the color of a QAction that is in a toolbar?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qaction, qtoolbar

I have a toolbar or there are several QActions. I would like to change the color of the QAction when it is selected so that the user can see the chosen action.

The problem is that QAction is not a QWidget so we can not use stylesheet.
Is there a way to get around this problem?
Or would it be better to declare QPushButton instead of QAction in my toolbar?

I would like, for example, that if I click on a QAction it is pushed against the others. I have 6 QAction declared in my toolbar.

Comment: In your [*QToolBar*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html), you can use [*QToolButton*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html) and `setCheckable(true)`, in this case, it is a QWidget so you can use style sheet

Comment: Thanks @Thibaut B. it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `checkeable` the `QAction` with:

```
your_action->setCheckable(true)
```

or using Qt Designer

[image]

and then set qss with QToolButton:

```
QToolButton:checked {background-color: red; }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @eyllanesc it works By cons I do not know why there is a negative vote

Comment: @Tom13000 
I do not really care about the downvote, I just made a comment. :)

Comment: How can I access the action on code? My action is not appearing under `ui->` nor under `ui->mainToolBar` (which is where it appears on UI). Where else should it be? I'm using Qt Creator 4.8.2 on Debian 10.